# How do I change a reference to a chart objects in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a macro I've recorded in excel.

The macro:

1. inserts 2 graphs
2. selects the 1st graph
3. Puts certain data on a secondary vertical axis

The macro works up to the below line and gives the error:

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate

Does anyone know a way I can get rid of the "Chart 17" part of it and replace it with something that does not need to reference Chart 17 or any numbered chart?

Thanks in Advance

EDIT - Apologies, below is the code for creating the graph which works and the graph editing which doesnt

```
Sub PLOTGraph()
Range("B:B,D:D,F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L").Select
Range("L1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=9
Range("B:B,D:D,F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L,N:N,P:P,R:R,T:T").Select
Range("T1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=10
  Range("B:B,D:D,F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L,N:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB,AD:AD").Select
Range("AD1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=7
Range( _
     "B:B,D:D,F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L,N:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB,AD:AD,AF:AF,AH:AH,A     J:AJ,AL:AL" _
).Select
Range("AL1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=8
Range( _
"B:B,D:D,F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L,N:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB,AD:AD,AF:AF,AH:AH,A    J:AJ,AL:AL,AN:AN,AP:AP,AR:AR,AT:AT" _
).Select
Range("AT1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=7
Range( _
"B:B,D:D,F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L,N:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB,AD:AD,AF:AF,AH:AH,A    J:AJ,AL:AL,AN:AN,AP:AP,AR:AR,AT:AT,AV:AV" _
).Select
Range("AV1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Select
End Sub

    Sub PREPGRAPH()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 17").IncrementLeft 307.4175590551
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 17").IncrementTop -7.4175590551
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 17").ScaleWidth 2.2901131822, msoFalse, _
msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 17").ScaleHeight 2.4446731852, msoFalse, _
msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(13).Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(12).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).AxisGroup = 2
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).Select
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(12).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(13).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(13).AxisGroup = 2
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(13).Select
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(12).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(14).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(14).AxisGroup = 2
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(14).Select
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(12).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(15).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(15).AxisGroup = 2
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(15).Select
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(12).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(16).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(16).AxisGroup = 2
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(16).Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = _
"Voltage (V) & Temperature (?)"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
"Voltage (V) & Temperature (?)"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 29).ParagraphFormat
.TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
 End With
 With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 7).Font
.BaselineOffset = 0
 .Bold = msoFalse
.NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
.NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
.Fill.Transparency = 0
.Fill.Solid
.Size = 10
.Italic = msoFalse
.Kerning = 12
.Name = "+mn-lt"
.UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
.Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(8, 20).Font
.BaselineOffset = 0
.Bold = msoFalse
.NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
.NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
.Fill.Transparency = 0
.Fill.Solid
.Size = 10
.Italic = msoFalse
.Kerning = 12
.Name = "+mn-lt"
.UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
.Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(28, 2).Font
.BaselineOffset = 0
.Bold = msoFalse
.NameComplexScript = "Times New Roman"
.NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
.Fill.Transparency = 0
.Fill.Solid
.Size = 10
.Italic = msoFalse
.Kerning = 12
.Name = "Times New Roman"
.UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
.Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Time (s)"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Time (s)"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).ParagraphFormat
.TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).Font
.BaselineOffset = 0
.Bold = msoFalse
.NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
.NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
.Fill.Transparency = 0
.Fill.Solid
.Size = 10
.Italic = msoFalse
.Kerning = 12
.Name = "+mn-lt"
.UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
.Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Text = "Voltage (V)"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Voltage (V)"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).ParagraphFormat
.TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).Font
.BaselineOffset = 0
.Bold = msoFalse
.NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
.NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
.Fill.Transparency = 0
.Fill.Solid
.Size = 10
.Italic = msoFalse
.Kerning = 12
.Name = "+mn-lt"
.UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
.Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to provide more than a single line of your code - all of the relevant VBA would be useful.

Comment: In Sub PREPGRAPH(), you have the code line that you say causes an error several times `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate`. I think this is because you are using a recorded macro. Your Chart name will change if you keep running the code to make the chart. Maybe read through the code and think about what you actually want to keep, so you can delete unnecessary lines and focus on cleaning up the remaining lines.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the index of the Chart Object. If it will always be the 1st one, the code is different than if it is always the second to last one.

```
Dim i As Integer
If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        i = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count -1 'second to last
        ' if always want i = 1, you can just use 1 instead of i
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Activate
        'do whatever with your chart here
Else
        MsgBox "no charts"
End If
```

Comment: Hi Jessi, thanks for your reply. When you say 'do whatever with your chart here' did you mean cut and paste from ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 17").Activate to the end but replace 17 with i?

Comment: i would not do that. Your code has a lot of `Activate` instances, so I think it is doing more than you actually want. However, yes. In there, you would put your code. It may be easier to store a reference to that chart. At the beginning of your sub, `Dim myChart As ChartObject` then, after you define i, you can `myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i)` and then, you can `With myChart` and do all of the changes that you need to. ChartObject has these functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject